# How to correct the error by using tkinter lib

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to open the Excel file and print the file name, but the printer is not working

I don't know where I'm wrong

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

filename = ""

def browse_file():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:", title = "Select a File",  filetypes =(("excel files","*.xlsx"),("all files", "*.*")))

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")

file_explorer_button = Button(root, text = "Select File", command = browse_file).pack()
print(filename)  
root.mainloop()
```

[image]
[image]
***There are no errors except that the "print(filename)" is not working***

Answer (score 1):

The print statement needs to be in your function.

Comment: Any other way? execute  print  outside of the function?

Comment: Right now the print statement is printing a blank line. Because you are using a gui everything inside the mainloop is only ran once initially. After you press the button it does not go onto the next line. If you want to print the file name outside of the function you have to move the print below root.mainloop() but it will only print when you have closed the tkinter gui

Answer (score 1):

Move `print(filename)` in line 7 in `browse_file` function.

Try this:

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
 
def browse_file():
     
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:", title = "Select a File",  filetypes =(("excel files","*.xlsx"),("all files", "*.*")))
    print(filename)
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")

file_explorer_button = Button(root, text = "Select File", command = browse_file)
file_explorer_button.pack()
  
root.mainloop()
```